# how to rach model from the other model in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

if i have model called **Reaction** and it has ForeignKey refers to the other model called **User**.

now i know that i can reach the **User** model from the **Reaction** model

[image]

but i have a list of more that 1000 users came from **User** model , and i want to reach the ractions of them from the **Reaction** model.

how can i do that without taking each **user** from User model and get it through **Reaction** model.

these are my models :

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()







class Reaction(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None, related_name="reaction_from_user")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None, related_name="reaction_to_user")
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    type_of_reaction = models.TextField()
    have_been_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False , null=True)
```

Comment: Do you mean / have you tried `Reaction.objects.filter(from_user__in=users)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `reverse relationship` in Django.
As you have mentioned, you already have a list of users let's say `target_users = User.objects.filter()`, and then you can use the following code to get the reactions for your target users:

```
reactions_for_users = Reaction.objects.filter(to_user__in=target_users)
```